# Crystal Report SP34 64 does not work in VS2022

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

I installed SAP Crystal Report Version 13 SP34 For Visual Studio 2022 64bit (CRforVS6413SP34_0-80007712) From SAP Website. But After I installed Nothing Added to Visual Studio.
OS: Windows 10 22H2
What Should I do to have crystal report in vs 2022?
Thanks

I installed 64 bit version and run time .after that when I did not get answer I installed 32 bit one ,too. It doesn't work too.

Comment: I had the same problem as you and I applied simultaneously the answers of @MilletSoftware and micrown and it worked. so I do not know which is right

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest Crystal Report - Visual Studio Developer edition from the below link.

https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

and install it using 'Run As Administrator'

then

Crystal Report ItemTemplate and Project Templates need to be copied from

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE"

To

C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates

it's working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the CRforVS6413SP34_0-80007712.exe and select **Run as Administrator**.

Answer (score 0):

If the Crystal Reports project templates don't appear, try renaming or deleting the AppData folder to reset your vs2022 (just like a new user)
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_xxxx