# Crystal Report error in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

I was using Crystal Report through VS2010 before. However, this time, we switched the source code to VS2022.

I tried to fix the Crystal Report screen I developed in VS2010 in VS2022, but an error occurred.

Symptoms are not loaded by the designer and cannot be corrected, and the developed screen does not open.

I reinstall CRforVS_13_0_10.exe

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 required Crystal Report SP32 (or later).

you can download the latest Crystal Report developer edition from the below link.

[Crystal Report Download Link](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html)

[Compaitlble Crystal Report versions for Visual Studio](https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/crystalreports/3354091173.html)

if the crystal report template missing in Visual Studio then you need to copy the template as per the below link

[Crystal Report SP34 64 does not work in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265492/crystal-report-sp34-64-does-not-work-in-vs2022)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).